# python 'AttributeError' with can.BLFReader

Tags: python

I am trying to import blf file using can.BLFReader module.

buf python shows 'AttributeError'.

this is the code.

```
import can
filename = "test.blf"
can_log = can.BLFReader(filename)
for msg in logging:
    print(msg)
```

AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'BLFReader'

and the file name is not 'can'

what is the reason?

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly your environment - versions of python and python-can and how you're actually trying to run this. A minimal conda create is a good way to allow someone to reproduce your issue. And knowing whether this is being run from python or ipython will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with python3 version if you run as you can see in the attached image[image] with python it will work

Comment: Thanks. i can see it same with your image.
then, what is the difference between running of python and jupyter?